# Session Management: Insufficient Session ID Entropy

Tags: sessionid, session-management

The session ID variables in my endpoint are predictable and it shows vulnerability "**Insufficient Session ID Entropy**" in the scan result. I would like to ask if these variables can be modified?

Also, the suggested fix is to ensure that the session ID must be properly generated by using a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (PRNG). Can you suggest how to apply this fix if this is feasible? Or is there any other way to remediate the vulnerability?